# NameError ActionController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting an error message in the following code:
NameError in PurchasesController#create
uninitialized constant Purchase::PurchaseCodeID

`purchase_controller.rb`:

```
class PurchasesController < ApplicationController

    def create
        #if @memberTier = PurchaseCode.find_by(Code: 123456).Code then
            @purchase=Purchase.create(purchase_params)
            redirect_to :back
        #end
    end

    def index
        @purchases = Purchase.where(UserID: current_user.id)
        @sum = Purchase.where(UserID: current_user.id).sum(:Points)
        @redemp = Redemption.where(UserID: current_user.id).sum(:RedemptionID)
        @deff = RedemptionDetail.where(RedemptionID: @redemp).sum(:Points)
        @ans = @sum - @deff
    end

    def new
        @purchase = Purchase.new(purchase_params)
    end

    def purchase_params
        params.require(:purchase).permit(:PurchaseID,:PurchaseCodeID,:Points, :UserID)
    end



end
```

`purchase.rb`:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
     validates :PurchaseCodeID, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }


    def self.create(purchase_params)

        begin
            @purchaseid = Purchase.last.id
            @purchaseid = @purchaseid + 1
        rescue
            @purchaseid = 1 
        end
        @code = PurchaseCode.find_by(Code: PurchaseCodeID).Code
        @purchase = Purchase.new(purchase_params)
        @purchase.PurchaseCodeID = @code
        @purchase.PurchaseID = @purchaseid
        @purchase.UserID = User.current.id
        @userTier = User.current.TierID
        @tierPoint = MembershipTier.find_by(TierID: @userTier).RequiredPoint
        @purchase.Points = @tierPoint
        @purchase.save


    end





end
```

`view/purchases/index.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Purchase History</h1>
<p>


  Enter the code here:</br>

<%= form_for :purchase, url: purchases_path do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.text_field :PurchaseCodeID %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>

  </thead>

<tbody>
  <% @purchases.each do |purchase| %>

      <tr>
         <td><%= purchase.Points %></td>
         <td>|<%= purchase.created_at.to_s.to_date.strftime("%e %B, %Y") %></td>
         <td><%= purchase.created_at.to_s.to_time.strftime("| %I:%M %P") %></td>
      </tr>



  <% end %>

  </tbody>
</table>

  <tr>
  <td><p>Current Points: <%= @ans %></p></td>
  </tr>


<%= link_to t('sign_out'), destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

I'm using rails 4. Hope that someone will help me to solve my problem.  Thank you.

Comment: This line in your model is wrong: `@code = PurchaseCode.find_by(Code: PurchaseCodeID).Code` In that line `PurchaseCodeID` is undefined. What are you trying to do there? Seems like you should be passing a variable into that method and using that variable instead of `PurchaseCodeID`, but you're not doing that.

Comment: I'm trying to get the value of my PurchaseCodeID and find its Code value inside the PurchaseCode table. PurchaseCodeID will be given by the user. It's a field text name.

Comment: How to pass a variable to a method? I have no idea. I tried to search it to google but I understand nothing.

Comment: Maybe I've forgotten too much of my Rails, but what is with `@purchases = Purchase.where(UserID: current_user.id)`? Does Rails care if your symbol starts with an uppercase letter? I've never seen that. I don't think Ruby cares if your symbols start with an upper case, but :cat most definitely does not equal :Cat. I think you are asking for a nightmare when another Rails developer has to read that code. Is this a way of calling the relation that I'm not familiar with? And `@purchase.UserID = User.current.id` works?Is someone missing the whole point of "convention over configuration"?

Comment: "How to pass a variable to a method? I have no idea. I tried to search it to google but I understand nothing." No offense but that's an understatement. I have to assume someone else wrote this code, since you'd have to understand passing variables to methods to have written it. But it's written in a coding style learned from some other language. So Many UpperCase Letters!

Comment: "@purchase.UserID = User.current.id" is working. My only problem is with "@code = PurchaseCode.find_by(Code: PurchaseCodeID).Code" . I worked before with other project using Rails and this kind of method is not my problem. And yes Rails cares my cases and I understand that.

Comment: I mean, is there a better method to make this kind of method that I used? Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PurchaseCodeID` seems to be in `purchase_params`, so you should change this line:

```
@code = PurchaseCode.find_by(Code: PurchaseCodeID).Code
```

to:

```
@code = PurchaseCode.find_by(Code: purchase_params[:PurchaseCodeID]).Code
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please be aware that you're doing some very unusual things in your code. E.g. setting the `@purchaseid` manually. That should be an automatically incremented column in your database. Anyway, I guess you're still learning. Good luck.